# SQL server can't start to connect?

Tags: database, process, windows-10, sql-server-express

Sql server reports a service error

> Windows could not start the SQl server (SQLEXPRESS) service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly

Images which describe the problem from the moment SQL Server was started, as follows:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your Application and System event logs. You likely have a misconfiguration.

Comment: Check windows error logs. You won't be able to connect (second image) until the service starts (first image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Turns out Microsoft dot net framework 2.0 was corrupted. This was only determined while trying to repair the SQL install and received a prompt regarding dot net 2.0. So we cancelled the SQL repair and instead repaired the .Net 2.0 installation. Rebooted and SQL agent started automatically. Hope this helps.

2.Check the windows event viewer.

3.Also check the SQL Error log - if the service stayed up long enough to start writing to that, it may provide some useful information.